# Are there guidelines on interpreting Match Quality for HERE geocoder results?

Tags: here-api

I am geocoding a number of addresses using the HERE geocoder REST API, and in my results I get back [match quality information](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-type-response-geocode.html#match-quality).  There is a `Relevance` score, which seems to be an overall "quality" rating on a scale of 0-1, with 1 being the best.  But in my dataset I'm having a hard time teasing out if there's a threshold where an address results shouldn't be used or not.  For example, some addresses are merely a city name, and they come back with a very low relevance score but a `MatchLevel` of city, and the geocode appears to be in the city center.  In this context I would say it is accurate and correct given the input.

Other address lookups have a `MatchCode` of "exact" and a level of HomeAddress, but still have a relatively middle to low Relevance score.

Does HERE provide any sort of guidelines on how the various match quality metrics equate to accuracy?  I think what I'm looking for is any sort of insight into how the various MatchQuality, MatchLevel, MatchCode, and MatchType work together so I can better determine a level of confidence in a geocode result.

Answer (score 1):

In general MatchLevel shows that the most specific part of the match was house number. The match quality (which goes from 0 to 1) indicates a good match. A MatchType of pointAddress indicates that the exact address exists on the map. Other addresses are approximate and interpolated based on address ranges on the street segment they are on. The MatchType in those cases is interpolated and the result is usually less accurate than a pointAddress.

Some more details in documentation
https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-type-response-geocode.html

Comment: Thanks!  That lines up mostly with what I was thinking.  I also reached out via email to HERE's support and they provided a very nice detailed "Blue Paper" document explaining how the different measurements work.  I don't know that is is available to download unless requested, but it also helped answer my questions.

Comment: Also, I think my main takeaway from their document was that I had thought "Relevance" was an overall quality score.  But instead it seems to be a measurement of how many of your original search terms appear in their search results. It may effectively not matter, but it changed my perspective of how it was working.